# Swift Little endian hex value to decimal

Tags: ios, swift, endianness

I'm having difficulties implementing a function converting hex value(little endian) to decimal value.

So I'm writing function:

```
func convertHexLittleEndianToDeciaml(input:String) -> (int)
```

and Input is always 4 bytes(so 8 characters in input string)

value for `convertHexLittleEndianToDeciaml("606d0000")` should return `28,000`

Comment: 6d60 is 28,000 in decimal, not 280.

Comment: And what does it return? Show us your code and tell us where it fails :)

Comment: Why is your input a string an not an Int?

Comment: How short/large can the input string be? Why has it an odd number of characters in your example?

Comment: Sorry guys, i just updated question.@WMios @Martin $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write something like this:
(See UPDATEs)

```
func convertHexLittleEndianToDeciaml(input:String) -> Int32 {
    if let beValue = Int32(input, radix: 16) where input.characters.count == 8 {
        return beValue.byteSwapped
    } else {
        //or `fatalError()` or `return 0` or ...
        return Int32.min
    }
}

print(convertHexLittleEndianToDeciaml("606d0000")) //->28000
```

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry, but the code above have some overflow issue, happens with something like "FF010000":

```
func convertHexLittleEndianToDeciaml(input:String) -> Int32 {
    if let beValue = UInt32(input, radix: 16) where input.characters.count == 8 {
        return Int32(bitPattern: beValue.byteSwapped)
    } else {
        //or `fatalError()` or `return 0` or ...
        return Int32.min
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2**

So, I have found that returning a valid `Int32` in error case might cause a bug which cannot easily be found. I recommend you to change the return type to Optional and return nil in error case.

```
func convertHexLittleEndianToDeciaml(input:String) -> Int32? {
    guard let beValue = UInt32(input, radix: 16) where input.characters.count == 8 else {
        return nil
    }
    return Int32(bitPattern: beValue.byteSwapped)
}

if let value = convertHexLittleEndianToDeciaml("606d0000") {
    print(value) //->28000
} else {
    print("Hex format invalid")
}
```

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @androisojavaswift, I fixed some issue in my first answer. Please use the latter code.

Comment: Also it is good to note that integer initialization( init(: radix:) ) with  a string and radix as 16 has to have the string in big endian representation. That explains why byteSwapped is used as the questioner requires a little endian interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works for longer numbers that I wrote:

```
func convert(number: String) -> Int {
    var formatted = number
    if number.count <= 16 {
        let difference = 16 - number.count
        for _ in 0..<difference {
            formatted.append("0")
        }
    } else {
        return 0
    }

    let value = UInt64(formatted, radix: 16) ?? 0
    let z = value.byteSwapped
    let final = UInt64(bitPattern: Int64(z))
    return Int(final)
}
```